# The uniform floats in this vertex shader don't work

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-shader

Details:
 This shader draws an orbit path of a planet around a star.  My intention is to dim the color of the path when it gets farther away from the opengl camera using the uniform floats "near" and "far" to help calculate the color brightness.  When I try to use the uniform float variables, the shader doesn't work at all.  I have no idea what could be wrong.  (I'm new at openGL and C++).

Vertex shader (Works if not using uniform float variables)

```
#version 450

layout(location=0) in vec3 vertex_position;

uniform mat4 proj, view; //view and projection matrix
uniform mat4 matrix;     // model matrix

uniform float near;   //closest orbit distance
uniform float far;    //farthest orbit distance
uniform vec3 dist_orbit_center;
out vec3 colour;

void main()
{
    vec3 dist_vector = dist_orbit_center + vertex_position;
    float dist = length(dist_vector);

    //Trying out some debugging. Ignoring dist for now
    //float ratio = near / far;  // Not working!
    float ratio = 0.25 / 0.5;  // Working!

    colour = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.1) * ratio;

    gl_Position = proj * view * matrix * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader (Works if not using uniform float variables)

```
#version 450

in vec3 colour;
out vec4 frag_colour;

void main() 
{
    frag_colour=vec4 (colour, 1.0);
}
```

C++ code for drawing planet orbit path (Working except for glUniform1f ?)

```
 if ((orb.flag))
{
    double near;
    double far;
    // get nearest and farthest point of orbit
    distance_to_orbit(near, far, cam.pos, sun.pos, plan[orb.body].orbit_radius, plan[orb.body].orbit_axis, Debug);
    GLfloat near_display = (float) (near / DISPLAY_FACTOR);
    GLfloat far_display = (float) (far / DISPLAY_FACTOR);

    glUseProgram(sh_orbit.program);
    glBindVertexArray(sh_orbit.vao);
    glUniformMatrix4fv (sh_orbit.view_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, cam.view_mat.m);
    mat4 m = identity_mat4();
    mat4 m2;
    m2 = translate(m, sun.display_pos);
    glUniformMatrix4fv (sh_orbit.matrix_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, m2.m);
    // For debugging.  Not working.
    near_display = 0.25;
    glUniform1f(sh_orbit.near_location,  near_display);
    // For debugging.  Not working.
    far_display = 0.5;
    glUniform1f(sh_orbit.far_location,  far_display);
    glUniform3fv(sh_orbit.dist_orbit_center_location, 1, sun.display_pos.v);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 361);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

C++ code for creating orbit path of planet for vertex shader (Working)

```
void Setup_planet_orbit(int index)
{
    orb.flag = 1;
    orb.body = index;
    vec3d axis = plan[orb.body].orbit_axis;
    vec3d globe = plan[orb.body].origonal_pos;

    for (int lp=0; lp<361; lp++)
    {
        globe = Rotate_point((double) lp * TO_RADIANS, axis, 
      plan[orb.body].origonal_pos);
       sh_orbit.points[lp*3] = (float) (globe.v[0] / DISPLAY_FACTOR);
       sh_orbit.points[lp*3+1] = (float) (globe.v[1] / DISPLAY_FACTOR);
       sh_orbit.points[lp*3+2] = (float) (globe.v[2] / DISPLAY_FACTOR);
    }
    glUseProgram(sh_orbit.program);
    glBindVertexArray(sh_orbit.vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sh_orbit.points_vbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  0, 361*3*sizeof(GLfloat), 
   sh_orbit.points);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

C++ code for initializing shader (Working)

```
bool Get_orbit_shader()
{
    float*& point = sh_orbit.points;
    point = (float*)malloc (3 * 361 * sizeof (float));

    string vertshader=readFile("orbit.vert.txt");
    const char* vertex_shader = vertshader.c_str();

    string fragshader=readFile("orbit.frag.txt");
    const char* fragment_shader = fragshader.c_str();
    // Compile vertex shader program
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    int params=-1;
    glGetShaderiv (vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &params);
    if (GL_TRUE != params)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: GL shader index %i did not compile\n", vs);
        print_shader_info_log(vs);
        return false;
    }
    // Compile fragment shader program
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    glGetShaderiv (fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &params);
    if (GL_TRUE != params)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: GL shader index %i did not compile\n", fs);
        print_shader_info_log(fs);
        return false;
    }
    // Link vertex and shader program
    sh_orbit.program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(sh_orbit.program, fs);
    glAttachShader(sh_orbit.program, vs);
    glLinkProgram(sh_orbit.program);
    //Check if linked correctly.
    glGetProgramiv(sh_orbit.program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &params);
    if (GL_TRUE !=params)
   {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not link shader programme GL index 
        %u\n", 
        sh_orbit.program);
        print_programme_info_log(sh_orbit.program);
        return false;
   }
   print_all(sh_orbit.program);
   mat4 matrix = identity_mat4();

   glUseProgram(sh_orbit.program);
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &sh_orbit.vao);
   glBindVertexArray(sh_orbit.vao);

   sh_orbit.view_mat_location = glGetUniformLocation(sh_orbit.program, 
   "view");
   glUniformMatrix4fv (sh_orbit.view_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, 
   cam.view_mat.m);

   sh_orbit.proj_mat_location = glGetUniformLocation (sh_orbit.program, 
   "proj");
   glUniformMatrix4fv (sh_orbit.proj_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, 
   cam.proj_mat.m);

   sh_orbit.proj_mat_location = glGetUniformLocation (sh_orbit.program, 
   "matrix");
   glUniformMatrix4fv (sh_orbit.matrix_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix.m);

   sh_orbit.near_location = glGetUniformLocation(sh_orbit.program, "near");
   glUniform1f (sh_orbit.near_location, 0);

   sh_orbit.far_location = glGetUniformLocation (sh_orbit.program, "far");
   glUniform1f (sh_orbit.far_location, 0);

   vec3 load;
   sh_orbit.dist_orbit_center_location = glGetUniformLocation 
   (sh_orbit.program, "dist_orbit_center");
   glUniform3f (sh_orbit.dist_orbit_center_location, load.v[0], load.v[1], 
   load.v[2]);

   glGenBuffers(1, &sh_orbit.points_vbo);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sh_orbit.points_vbo);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  361*3*sizeof(GLfloat), sh_orbit.points, 
   GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
   glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glBindVertexArray(0);

   return true;  
}
```

C++ code for finding nearest and farthest point of orbit in 3D space (Working)

```
/// Find closest and farthest distance to a 3d disk
/// projection of P-C onto plane is Q-C = P-C  -  Dot(N,P-C)*N
void distance_to_orbit(double &near, double &far, vec3d point, vec3d center, 
double radius, vec3d normal, FILE* Debug)
{
    vec3d PmC;
    vec3d QmC;
    vec3d diff;
    double lengthQmC;
    double sqr_dist;
    double dist;
    double temp;
    vec3d Closest;
    vec3d Farthest;
    vec3d vec_temp;

    PmC = point - center;
    double Dot = dot_d(normal, PmC);
    vec_temp = normal *  Dot;  //Distance to plane that circle is on.
    QmC = PmC - vec_temp;
    lengthQmC = length(QmC);

    vec_temp = QmC * (radius / lengthQmC);
    Closest = center + vec_temp;

    diff = point - Closest;
    sqr_dist = dot_d(diff, diff);
    near = sqrt(sqr_dist);     //distance to nearest point of 3d disc

    vec_temp = center - Closest;
    vec_temp *= 2.0f;
    diff = Closest + vec_temp;
    far = get_distance_d(point, diff);  //distance to farthest point of 3d 
    disc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you setting `far` (and `near`) to 0 in `glUniform1f (sh_orbit.far_location, 0);` expression and getting division by zero?

Comment: I put in non zero numbers but still not working.  Good catch though.  The program uses four other shaders so I'm going to add uniform floats to them and see if the same problem happens.

Comment: Also your code lacks any error handling. you should call `glGetError` after every other gl call and check the result returned.

Comment: Added some error checking.  Appears to be coming from this line of code.  mat4 m = identity_mat4();
          mat4 m2;
          m2 = translate(m, sun.display_pos);
          glUniformMatrix4fv (sh_orbit.matrix_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, 
          m2.m);

Comment: Ok, found one problem.  It seems shaders don't like underscores in the uniform variables.  'dist_orbit_center'.  So it's working now but when I add more uniform variables, they don't work.  Strange!!  @VTT